# Plone 4 - History for second workflow won't show in @@historyview

Tags: workflow, plone, dexterity

I have a dexterity content type in Plone 4.2.4. The versioning works fine with the `default workflow` for this content type, although it is not a workflow shipped with plone, but a custom made.

However, when I enable a second workflow for the same type, everything but the versioning works fine.

- additional permissions managed by the second workflow are working
- The state changes are working

The difference:

- I used different `state_variable` names for the workflows, which seems to make sense, to have a catalogable field for the state of the second workflow.

I've tried to use the same state variable name, but that didn't help. I have the workflow variable `review_history` also set in the 2nd workflow and sufficient permissions in the context.
I am (mostly) shure, that I got the permission concept, but I have no clou, how permissions get calculated, when multiple workflows are involved.

Any idea, why the second workflow does not leave a trace in my content types history?

Thanks very much in advance.

**Udate**

I've reordered the workflows as Ida Ebkes suggested and did see, that all transitions from the 2nd workflow get stored properly. So it seems to be an issue with the historyview.

Since these workflows indeed describe concurrent behaviors of a content type, I really would like to stick with separate workflows and ideally different workflow state variables and catalog indexes.

What I now think needs to be done, is to tweak the historyview.

Comment: I can confirm your observations, only the transitions of the first assigned wf are tracked in the history. But this appears to concern only the history-form. The modifications seem to be stored completely, because if you switch the order of the wf's, older modifications of the new first wf are visible, also. Would you like to give some more insights of your use-case? Maybe there are other ways to solve your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint. I had the feeling, that it gets stored, but not displayed, but found no way to confirm my feeling about this. The reordering of the workflows, assigned to my type shows that theese transitions get stored.

Comment: Even more oddly, if you change the order of wf's and the current state is one of the now 2nd-wf, the state cannot be displayed, instead one of the new wf-states is displayed!? Anyway, you write your workflows 'describe concurrent behaviours', hard to guess, what that means exactly, but any chance, placeful-wf can help you here?

Comment: @Ida Ebkes: The term "concurrent behavior" is actually from a tutorial about plone WF's and just means, that more than one chain of states is needed, to describe all needed states of an object.

Comment: Ah ok, reading helps ;) The article also gives a usecase: "For example, an object may be published, but require translation. You can track the review state in the main workflow and the translation state in another."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I did it. It works for plone 4.2.4 at least.

Since the problem was a display problem, I just had to tweak my historyviewlet. Therefore, I created a folder named `viewlets` in my product root and created a `__init__.py` and a `configure.zcml` file. Then i copied `content_history.pt`, `history_view.pt`, `review_history.pt` and `content.py` from `plone/app/layout/viewlets/` (omelette) to the newly created folder.

The `configure.zcml` contains two view registrations:

```
<browser:view
    for="*"
    name="my-contenthistory"
    class=".content.ContentHistoryView"
    permission="zope2.View"
    />

<browser:page
    for="*"
    name="my-historyview"
    template="history_view.pt"
    permission="zope2.View"
    />
```

Furthermore, I copied the whole `WorkflowHistoryViewlet` class from `content.py` to a different class name. `TransferHistory` in this case. Then I changed mostly the part that corresponds to the workflow state variable, which was not `review_state`, but `transfer_state`. I further found that the initial usage of the 2nd workflow creates also a `created` entry in the history of the 2nd workflow, that I just filtered .

```
transfer_history = [x for x in transfer_history if x['action'] != None]
```

The I corrected the view name in `history_view.pt` to my new view name.

```
<div tal:replace="structure here/@@my-contenthistory">Content History</div>
```

Finally, I added my class as parent to the `ContentHistoryViewlet` class in `content.py`

```
class ContentHistoryViewlet(WorkflowHistoryViewlet, TransferHistoryViewlet):

    index = ViewPageTemplateFile("content_history.pt")

    @memoize
    def getUserInfo(self, userid):

    [...]

    def fullHistory(self):
        history = self.workflowHistory() + self.revisionHistory() + self.transferHistory()
        if len(history) == 0:
            return None
        history.sort(key=lambda x: x["time"], reverse=True)
        return history
```

and registered the .zcml in the products `configure.zcml`

```
 <include package=".viewlets" />
```

Then I modified `content_history.pt` and also changed the definition of `action_id` in the upper part of the file.

```
[...]
action_id python:item['action'] or item.get('review_state', False) or item.get('transfer_state', False);
[...]
```

After rebooting the monster and a product reinstall, all state changes from both workflows are shown in the my-historyview.